# How to get groupby to start counting seconds at a given time every day?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas df with DateTimeIndex like this:

```
time
2016-06-10 10:09:16        0.0
2016-06-10 13:18:08    11332.0
2016-06-13 09:00:22        0.0
2016-06-13 10:14:12     4430.0
2016-06-13 13:27:14    11582.0
2016-06-13 15:15:59     6525.0
2016-06-13 16:25:25     4166.0
2016-06-14 09:29:23        0.0
2016-06-14 13:12:31    13388.0
2016-06-14 16:25:28    11577.0
```

The column shows seconds since last observation/row and it is reset every day like this:

```
def time_calc(df):
    res = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0)
    df = df.join(res)
    return df

df = df.groupby(df.index.date, group_keys=False).apply(time_calc)
```

However, I would like the counting of seconds to start at 09:00:00 every day so that my df should look like this:

```
time
2016-06-10 10:09:16     4156.0
2016-06-10 13:18:08    11332.0
2016-06-13 09:00:22       22.0
2016-06-13 10:14:12     4430.0
2016-06-13 13:27:14    11582.0
2016-06-13 15:15:59     6525.0
2016-06-13 16:25:25     4166.0
2016-06-14 09:29:23     1763.0
2016-06-14 13:12:31    13388.0
2016-06-14 16:25:28    11577.0
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you want to do now. You can accomplish this in two steps.

First, calculate the time difference for everything other than the first value. This can be accomplished by `groupby` + `shift`. The first value is always set to `NaT` so you can then just set that as the time difference from `9:00:00`

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.reset_index()
df['seconds'] = df.groupby(df.time.dt.date).time.apply(lambda x: x -x.shift(1))
df.loc[df.seconds.isnull(), 'seconds'] = df.loc[df.seconds.isnull(), 'time'] - pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df.seconds.isnull(), 'time'].astype('str').replace('(?<=\s).*', '9:00:00', regex=True))
df['seconds'] = df.seconds.dt.total_seconds()
df = df.set_index('time')

#                     seconds
#time                        
#2016-06-10 10:09:16   4156.0
#2016-06-10 13:18:08  11332.0
#2016-06-13 09:00:22     22.0
#2016-06-13 10:14:12   4430.0
#2016-06-13 13:27:14  11582.0
#2016-06-13 15:15:59   6525.0
#2016-06-13 16:25:25   4166.0
#2016-06-14 09:29:23   1763.0
#2016-06-14 13:12:31  13388.0
#2016-06-14 16:25:28  11577.0
```

Comment: There is no data between 16:30:00 and 09:00:00

Comment: @cJc okay, see my edit. I now understand what you want.

Comment: Almost there I think. Can we do this by keeping the timestamps in the index or is it strictly necessary to add the 'time' column?

Comment: @cJc Sorry I didn't realize it was an index. Can you just do `df = df.reset_index()` at the beginning and then `df = df.set_index('time')` at the end? That seems like the most straight forward way around this. 

The problem is that you can't use `.shift()` with a `DatetimeIndex` but there might be other ways around it.

Comment: It works and it's fast. Thank you for your help! PS! Your second row should read: df['seconds'] = df.groupby(df.time.dt.day)['time'].apply(lambda x: x -x.shift(1))

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, incase your actual `df` has more than 1 column.

Comment: I just had the chance to test your snippet on my real data, and it turns out something funny happens when the data gets into second, third month etc. Your second line of code could should read: 'df['seconds'] = df.groupby(df.time.dt.date).time.apply(lambda x: x -x.shift(1))
' and then it all works as expected. Tnx again.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best answer but it works.

You can use [Time Deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) to find this. Assuming your Pandas Dataframe or Series is saved as `pd.datetimes`, which you can do by using [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) you can just subtract out 9 hours from the datetime then get all of the seconds in that timedelta and then modulo by 86,400 which is the number of seconds in a day.

```
pd.to_timedelta(df -  dt.timedelta(hours=9)).dt.total_seconds() % 86400
```

which will give the output:

```
0     4156.0
1    15488.0
2       22.0
3     4452.0
4    16034.0
5    22559.0
6    26725.0
7     1763.0
8    15151.0
9    26728.0
```

Then you will need to use list comprehension to finish it off:

```
s2 = [x-y if d1==d2 else x for x,y,d1,d2 in zip(df.seconds[1:], df.seconds[:-1], my_days[1:], my_days[:-1])]
s2.insert(0, df.seconds[0])

 4156.0
11332.0
   22.0
 4430.0
11582.0
 6525.0
 4166.0
 1763.0
13388.0
11577.0
```

if you want them to be integers instead of floats you can use .astype(int) after you assign it to a column using `pd.DataFrame.assign()` if it is a dataframe or create a dataframe if you are working with a series. If you want your index to become a column simply use `df.reset_index()`.

---

My interactive session looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt     
time = [ "2016-06-10 10:09:16", "2016-06-10 13:18:08", "2016-06-13 09:00:22", "2016-06-13 10:14:12", "2016-06-13 13:27:14", "2016-06-13 15:15:59", "2016-06-13 16:25:25", "2016-06-14 09:29:23", "2016-06-14 13:12:31", "2016-06-14 16:25:28"]
my_time = pd.Series(time)
my_time = pd.to_datetime(my_time)
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'datetime':my_time.values, 
     'seconds':pd.to_timedelta(my_time -  dt.timedelta(hours=9)).dt.total_seconds() % 86400
   })
my_days = df.datetime.dt.day
s2 = [x-y if d1==d2 else x for x,y,d1,d2 in zip(df.seconds[1:], df.seconds[:-1], my_days[1:], my_days[:-1])]
s2.insert(0, df.seconds[0])
df.loc[:, "seconds"] = s2
print(df)
             datetime  seconds
0 2016-06-10 10:09:16   4156.0
1 2016-06-10 13:18:08  11332.0
2 2016-06-13 09:00:22     22.0
3 2016-06-13 10:14:12   4430.0
4 2016-06-13 13:27:14  11582.0
5 2016-06-13 15:15:59   6525.0
6 2016-06-13 16:25:25   4166.0
7 2016-06-14 09:29:23   1763.0
8 2016-06-14 13:12:31  13388.0
9 2016-06-14 16:25:28  11577.0
```

Comment: Tnx for your efforts. If I understand your code correctly, it calculates the number of seconds since 09:00:00 for every row and day? On any given day I want the first row to count from 09:00:00, but the following rows for any given day to be calculated from the previous row.. Hope this is clear enough? So, first row of the day -> calculate from 09:00:00, second row of the day calculate from first row, third row count from second row..

Comment: @cJc Using [list comprehension will help](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The answer is not the most efficient but If I understand properly it should work.